# Can't display image in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I'm new in Objective-C and Xcode. I did a very simple Mac app just to understand how to display the images in Cocoa. I'm working with Xcode 5.1.1. under OS X 10.9.2. One **Image Well** object to display images from the files (files .png are kept in the Assets Catalog inside the project). One button to change image. The initial image (10.png file) should be displayed by the **awakeFromNib** procedure. After pressing the button the image in the **Image Well** should change to 5.png-image. With the Interface Builder I established one action for the button and one outlet for **Image Well**.

Here is a code:

```
//  AppDelegate.h
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSImageView *changeImage;
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
- (IBAction)set5:(id)sender;
@end

//  AppDelegate.m
#import "AppDelegate.h"
@implementation AppDelegate
- (void)awakeFromNib
{   NSImage *im10;
    im10 = [NSImage imageNamed:@"10.png"];
    if (!im10) NSLog(@"im10 is nil");
    [_changeImage setImage:im10];
}
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification { }

- (IBAction)set5:(id)sender {
    NSImage *im5;
    im5 = [NSImage imageNamed:@"5.png"];
    if (!im5) NSLog(@"im5 is nil");
    [_changeImage setImage:im5];
}
@end
```

After launch there is no image in the **Image Well**, no image after pressing the button. The problem is in connecting to the .png files by **imageNamed** function: both **NSLogs** are printing "im5/im10 is nil", the same I saw while debugging. I tried to put the full path to specify the file, I tried to work with .tiff file - no results.

What's wrong with my app?
Thanks.

Comment: You created a new topic for same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23432528/once-again-how-to-display-images-with-nsimageview-in-xcode You need to edit according to suggestions from users your first question, no creating a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`imageNamed:` expects no file extension. Try using `[NSImage imageNamed:@"5"]`.